# Content Types not displaying when selecting new button

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a document library which is set to allow management of content types.
I have added several content types (which are document sets). For each of the document sets I have specified the allowable content types.

At the library level when I click "New" it shows the allowable Document Sets - no issue there. When I click "New" inside the Document Set, the specified content types are displayed correctly except for one content type. I have hunted through all the settings and checked that they match.

I have set up 10 different Document Sets and the other 9 work no problem. I'm wandering whether it is related to this being the "first" Document Set?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Content types specified against the Document Set (named "Entitlement")]

[image: Content types displayed when clicking the New button within the Document Set]